# Odd Regular Expression

Tags: regex

I'd like to create a regular expression in perl that can find an SSN in a given text file while not matching a nine digit number preceded by specific text.  The expression I have:

```
(?!.*X-MICROSOFT-CDO-OWNERAPPTID:-?)^.*(\b(?!000)(?!666)(?!9)[0-9]{3}[ -]?(?!00)[0-9]{2}[ -]?(?!0000)[0-9]{4}\b)
```

What I want to ignore:
X-MICROSOFT-CDO-OWNERAPPTID:-444444444

or

X-MICROSOFT-CDO-OWNERAPPTID:444444444

But I'd like to match any possible SSN besides that text.  With the above expression it will match everything before a valid SSN.  Any suggestions?
[image]

Comment: What's the false positive we are supposed to be solving?

Comment: Sorry I was explaining the problem that caused me to create this regex.  I'm actually just wondering why this regex is matching the "ddd"

Comment: I think it is because of this part `^.*` it is not a denial as it is after a group match (a lookahead denial) you are saying that the line should start with anything.

Answer (score 0):

It's matching the `ddd` because the `^.*` in your pattern is matches everything from the beginning of the string up to the SSN. You'd have to extract the first capture group from the match if you want to get *just* the SSN. Precisely how you do that depends on the language / platform you're using.

You might also want to consider using a negative lookbehind, like this:

```
(?<!X-MICROSOFT-CDO-OWNERAPPTID:-?)(\b(?!000|666|9)[0-9]{3}[ -]?(?!00)[0-9]{2}[ -]?(?!0000)[0-9]{4}\b)
```

But this also depends a lot on what platform you're using. JavaScript, for example, does not support lookbehinds at all.

Comment: If you pull the hyphen out of the lookbehind, it will work in any flavor that *does* support them: `(?<!X-MICROSOFT-CDO-OWNERAPPTID:)-?`.  This still allows a hyphen before the first digit.  I'm assuming that's okay as long as the hyphen isn't preceded by that other stuff. (The `\b` would allow that, too.)

Comment: The documentation says Perl-compatible regular expressions so I'm guessing perl.

Comment: You don't know for sure in which environment you want this to work? That's a new one.

Comment: It's a mail gateway my friend.  I'm not developing something.

Comment: @ktothez Well, it's hard to know how we can help you if we don't have any code or know anything about the system your working on, and it's not really appropriate to include that in this question as it would dramatically alter the question and would likely make the entire post off topic. I recommend asking about this on [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/).

Comment: There you go p.s.w.g
This is now a stack question.

Answer (score 0):

Since the used program apparently doesn't allow to extract a capture group from the match, but always takes the full match, p.s.w.g's idea of using a negative lookbehind was good. Though, the specified lookbehind `(?<!X-MICROSOFT-CDO-OWNERAPPTID:-?)` may not work since PCRE don't allow lookbehinds with non-fixed width. Fortunately in this case we can use two fixed-width lookbehinds instead of the above (one with and one without the `-`):

```
(?<!X-MICROSOFT-CDO-OWNERAPPTID:-)(?<!X-MICROSOFT-CDO-OWNERAPPTID:)…
```